# Spring Batch: Unit testing a custom item reader

Tags: java, junit, spring-batch

I would like to find a way to unit test a custom ItemReader that I've written as a delegate for a MultiResourceItemReader.

Here is my Spring Batch XML configuration file:

```xml
<batch:job id="allegati" incrementer="jobParametersIncrementer">
    <batch:step id="allegati-import">
        <batch:tasklet>
            <batch:chunk reader="allegati-reader" writer="allegati-writer" commit-interval="1"/>
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>

<bean id="allegati-reader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resources" value="file:#{jobParameters['FILEPATH']}/*" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="allegati-filereader" />
</bean>

<bean id="allegati-writer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaItemWriter">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="allegati-filereader" class="it.infogroup.vertenze.porting.reader.AllegatiReader" />
```

And here is what I've attempted as a test (the class I want to test is AllegatiReader):

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:jobAllegati.xml"})
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class, StepScopeTestExecutionListener.class})
public class AllegatiTest { 

@Autowired
private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;
@Autowired
private AllegatiReader reader;
@PersistenceContext
protected EntityManager em;

public static final String PARAM_ID = "RUN ID";
public static final String PARAM_FILEPATH = "FILEPATH";
public static final String PARAM_FILEPATH_VALUE = "E:/Test/Vertenze/Porting/Allegati";

public StepExecution getStepExecution() {
    JobParametersBuilder jpb = new JobParametersBuilder();
    jpb.addString(PARAM_FILEPATH, PARAM_FILEPATH_VALUE);
    jpb.addLong(PARAM_ID, System.currentTimeMillis());

    StepExecution execution = MetaDataInstanceFactory.createStepExecution(jpb.toJobParameters());
    return execution;
}

@Test
public void testReader() throws Exception {
    Allegato allegato = reader.read();
    Assert.assertNotNull(allegato);;
}
```

My problem is that resources (i.e., the files present into FILEPATH) are not injected into my reader.

Comment: Can you post the exception you're getting?

Comment: @MichaelMinella I'm not getting a particular exception. Simply, the setResource method is never called automatically. I've "solved" the problem by changing the testReader method in order to manually set the resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess you are trying to test the delegate reader (Class AllegatiReader)? if thats the case and if you want to work with autowiring, you need to use the multiresourceitemreader as bean under test

### reason

- the multiresourceitemreader creates the complete delegate reader
  objects (complete with resource set)
- the (delegate) reader bean on itself won't (can't) be provided as a completely
  configured reader with resource